# Struts 1.x Map backed ActionForm with custom Object

Tags: struts, struts-1

In Struts1.x version how do I populate my custom FooType object so that I can set it into the map. Basically my jsp contains dynamic rows with multiple columns. I want to populate the multiple column values into FooType object for each dynamic row. But I am not able to get it how to set the values in the FooType object in JSP.

Appreciate if you can help me with an idea

```
public FooType{

String foo1;
String foo2
String foo3

public String getFoo1(){
     return foo1;
}
public String getFoo2(){
     return foo2;
}
public String getFoo3(){
     return foo3;
}


}


public FooForm extends ActionForm {

    private final Map values = new HashMap();

    public void setValue(String key, Object value) {
        values.put(key, value);
    }

    public Object getValue(String key) {
        return values.get(key);
    }

}
```

Comment: If you want to populate some object first you should make this object available.

Comment: FooType exists right, if you see the code snippet above. I want my map contains Key = index and values are of type FooType. I am not sure how to set that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combining Mapped properties with Indexed properties in Struts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720224/combining-mapped-properties-with-indexed-properties-in-struts)